# Laravel JWTAuth Custom User Model

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm developing web using Laravel and JWTAuth with default user model at

```
App\User
```

Now i'm changin the path of my models to

```
App\Models
App\Models\User
```

and i change the jwt config to this

```
'user' => 'App\Models\User',
```

but when i try to access my login page, it's show error like this

```
FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 126:
Class 'App\User' not found
```

what happening with this? i've changing the setting to App\Models but it's still load to App\ directory?

I re-serve the php artisan, and do composer dump-autoload

It's the same error.

Comment: Solution 1: Check the namespace. I think default user class is not coming with the namespace.
Solution 2 : run composer dump-autoloads this will auto load your newly added or name space modified classes.
Solution 3 : Create new custom user model class and extends it to default user model class provided by the laravel. Now use your newly created custom user model class along with the namespace everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my error,

there's one config called auth.php that must updated too

Thanks